# Typedefing enum "member"

Tags: c++

Suppose I have the following definition in `"foo.h"`

```
namespace Foo{
     enum Bar {
        A,
        B
     };
}
```

Why won't `typedef Foo::Bar::A a`compile when I include "`foo.h"`? How would I go about using a shorthand name for A?

Comment: A is not the name of a type.

Comment: ^ For the same reason `typedef 23 a;` doesn't work.

Comment: `Foo::Bar` is the enum. `Foo::Bar::A` is a value that can be assigned to the enum.

Comment: The compiler did give me that error, which is clearer now. But do I have to type the full name of A? (the close vote is unfair)

Comment: You don't have to type the full name. You can always pull the enum into the current namespace `using Foo::Bar;`, or introduce a type alias for it if you are in function scope `using Bar = Foo::Bar;`. It just so happens that both will make the enum constants usable directly as well (unless `Bar` is an enum class, but that's another matter).

Answer (score 2):

The `typedef` keyword is only used for aliasing types, not other kinds of entities.  `A` is not a type; it's a value.  If you want an alias for it, you could do `constexpr Foo::Bar a = Foo::A;`.